# Where can I find this paper on "Aristotle, Searle, and the mind-body problem"?

Tags: reference-request

I would really like to read this paper, but I can't find it on the net:

> Code, Alan D. (1991). Aristotle, Searle, and the mind-body problem. In Ernest Lepore & Robert Van Gulick (eds.), John Searle and His Critics. Cambridge: Blackwell.

Any ideas on where to look but google? I'm not an expert on academic research on the net, yet.

Comment: I have looked, but it appears to be only available physically, in libraries. Have you tried academic libraries nearby?

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone. I found it in the linguistics section of our library. Should have looked first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is of course no complete list, but things that helped me so far:

JSTOR - collects articles in journals and also has some books. The access is limited, though. I think you either need to pay or enter the page via a university. I checked, and they don't have the paper.

PhilPapers - a comprehensive directory of online philosophical articles and books by academic philosophers. Your paper is listed there, but not downloadable.

Libraries - My university has the book. If yours hasn't, you can still order it and they will send it to you.

The homepage of the author - in this case there is not even a publication list, but many authors put .pdf's of their articles in their profiles (e.g. Sider, to name but one).

A site that help me out sometimes is academia.edu: They also allow sharing of articles, but again, yours isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas on where to look but google? I'm not an expert on academic research on the net, yet.

Have you tried visiting a library?  If they don't have that volume, they can surely get it via Inter-Library Loan.

Is there really any reason to believe that the full text of a book from 1991 would be freely available on the internet?